# Why is bash interpreting characters that I have character escaped?

Tags: bash, quoting

Why is it that when I run curl against a REST API, the special characters (!) in my key are interpreted by the shell?

```
curl https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer '00DE0000000K0eM!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxxxx'"  
-bash: !AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxxx'": event not found
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900175/bash-avoid-filename-interpretation), using a single quote should prevent bash from interpeting the string

As a workaround, I tried using a \ character, however that causes the key to be rejected.

```
curl https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer '00DE0000000K0eM\!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxx'"  
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

**How can I prevent bash from interpreting the string?**

Comment: The simple answer would be `set +H`

Answer (score 3):

The history expansion character `!` is special even when it is between double quotes, but it loses its special meaning between single quotes.

Here, it is inside a double-quoted string `"Authorization: Bearer '00DE0000000K0eM!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxxxx'"`. The single quotes in that string are ordinary characters in that string, they are not interpreted specially. There is no single-quoted string here.

If you add a backslash, it protects the `!` from triggering history expansion, but the backslash itself remains. So you end up with the header `Authorization: Bearer '00DE0000000K0eM\!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxx'`.

If the header needs to be `Authorization: Bearer '00DE0000000K0eM!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxx'`, you can specify it this way:

```
curl https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer '\''00DE0000000K0eM!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxxxx'\'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrap the whole string with double quotes the ! *is* interpreted (the single quotes are then treated as a string contained with the double quotes).

Try:

```
curl https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"'"'00DE0000000K0eM!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxxxx'"'"
```

More than one quoted string can be used in a line. Also I'm using double quotes to wrap single quotes so they get treated as a string and not a string boundry marker.

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-4.2$ printf '%s\n' "aa'bb!cc'dd"
bash: !cc'dd": event not found (Not good)

bash-4.2$ printf '%s\n' "aa'bb\!cc'dd"
aa'bb\!cc'dd (Not good)

bash-4.2$ printf '%s\n' "aa'bb"\!"cc'dd"
aa'bb!cc'dd (Good)

bash-4.2$ printf '%s\n' "aa'bb"'!'"cc'dd"
aa'bb!cc'dd (Good)
```

That is, the bang has to be escaped by single quotes or a backslash (double quotes don't escape them). A backslash within double quotes will prevent history expansion, but the backslash will remain.

In that regard, `bash` behaviour is different from that of `(t)csh` (which `bash` borrowed that feature from) or `zsh` which remove that backslash that has been used to escape `!` as you'd expect.

If you never use history expansion, you can also disable it altogether to save you this kind of trouble with:

```
set +H
```

Answer (score 0):

The `!` followed by *...stuff..* in the Bash shell means to pull values from your shell's history. You can see the history with the `history` command. It's a list of commands you previously ran.

To dissuade the shell from interpreting this character simply wrap your argument in single quotes (`'`) or escape the `!`. In your case just escaping it should suffice, and drop the single quotes (`'`).

```
$ curl https://foo.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer 00DE0000000K0eM\!AQYAQGgmLxxxxxxxxx"
```